# Per action authentication handlers in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-authentication

Is it possible to have per action authentication handlers in ASP.NET Core? If so how?

I want to have some specific authentication mechanisms for a few routes. The others should be covered by the overall authentication handler.

Comment: I think you can use filters to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible! You can add a custom authentication scheme and implement your custom logic to handle the requests that are going to be using your new custom authentication scheme. Have a look at this https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/implementing-custom-authentication-scheme-and-handler-in-aspnet-core-3x